# Evento onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tenho um projeto com NavigationDrawer, na pagina principal tenho um menu, e nas outros fragmentos eu inflo, só que quando pressiono o voltar do navigationbar 'botão voltar do celular', ele fecha o aplicativo e não retorna 'ou retorna uma pagina ou um fragmento', queria que ao pressionar ele retornasse e não fechasse o app.

Segue o `onBackPressed`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Teria como dar mais detalhes do problema?

Comment: Tenho um projeto com NavigationDrawer, na pagina principal tenho um menu, e nas outros fragmentos eu inflo, só que quando pressiono o voltar do navigationbar 'botão voltar do celular', ele fecha o aplicativo e não retorna 'ou retorna uma pagina ou um fragmento', queria que ao pressionar ele retornasse e não fechasse o app.

Comment: Entendi. Edite sua pergunta e coloque seu comentário nela.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta no SOen:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530879/2570426

Comment: certo, eu consegui voltar pra um fragmento escolhido, e depois quando chega nele o voltar não faz mais nada, queria que quando chegasse no fragmento escolhido ai sim ele fechasse o app.

Comment: Como vc está criando os fragments?

Comment: No meu `onNavigationItemSelected` está o seguinte.

`Fragment meuFragmento = null;
        boolean fragmentoSelec = false;`

`if (id == R.id.nav_quem_somos) {
            meuFragmento = new quemSomos();
            fragmentoSelec = true;`

`if (fragmentoSelec == true) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_principal, meuFragmento).commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, pode tentar o seguinte:

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //retorna o drawer
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        // retorna todos os fragments que estão em backStack
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            //Volta o titulo pra Activity
            toolbar.setTitle("Activity");

        }

    }
    //fecha a aplicação, aqui você pode fazer voltar para alguma activity
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Quando chamar os fragments acrescente em todos  `addToBackStack(null)` da seguinte forma:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_principal, meuFragmento).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Exemplo no github: [onBackPressed](https://github.com/MurilloComino/ExampleDrawerStackOverflow)

Comment: Ainda está fechando o app.

Comment: Olá amigo, editei, testei aqui e para mim funcionou perfeitamente, tenta fazer desse jeito que mandei agora.

Comment: Se quiser te mando o exemplo simples que fiz pra teste.

Comment: Manda se for possível,

Comment: manda pra arimelo@outlook.com.br

Comment: Mas pra você desse jeito que coloquei, ainda não está voltando o fragment? e nem o drawer fecha quando clica no botão voltar? Coloquei o link do exemplo na edição da minha resposta

Comment: Murilo, se eu chamar o fragmento pelo menu e voltar ele funciona e volta para a tela anterior e depois fechar o app normal, mais eu coloquei uns botões na tela principal chamando os mesmos fragmentos, e quando volto ele fecha, não volta para o anterior.

Comment: Resolveu, coloquei essa linha `addToBackStack(null)` nos botões também.

Comment: @AriMelo esqueci de mencionar isso mesmo. Precisa colocar o addToBackStack() em todos os fragmentos para realizar a opção de voltar. Se tiver alguma dúvida a mais, eu te mandei um email no sábado só me responder por ele que eu ajudo. Abraço

Comment: Blz @MurilloComino, a única coisa que notei foi que, ao voltar pra tela inicial ele não está trocando o nome na barra toolbar, está ficando o nome do fragmento que se abre.

Comment: @AriMelo, editei a minha resposta, se você está chamando os titulos da toolbar dentro do fragment, alterando na sua MainActivity o  `onBackPressed()` na parte do `else if(...)` como editado na resposta dará certo, assim como testado e atualizado o projeto no github.